# trying to find file location, I got this error (Error Record, object or class type required)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I was trying to get file location (D:\Documents\Work) on edit components with this code

```
procedure TForm3.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if dlgOpen1.Execute then
    if FileExists(dlgOpen1.FileName) then
      edt5.Text.ExtractFileDir(dlgOpen1.FileName)
    else
      raise Exception.Create('File does not exist.');
end;
```

Comment: You don't need to use `FileExists()` if you instead enable the dialog's `ofPathMustExist` and `ofFileMustExist` flags. Then the dialog won't even close unless the user selects a file that really exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edt5.Text.ExtractFileDir(dlgOpen1.FileName)` is not valid. `edt5` appears to be a `TEdit`, and `TEdit` controls don't have a `Text.ExtractFileDir` method.

Your code should read

```
edt5.Text := ExtractFileDir(dlgOpen1.FileName);
```

Comment: ExtractFileDir and ExtractFilePath return the same thing in essence. The difference is the value returned by ExtractFileDir does not include a trailing file separator.